# How to circumvent existing instances (for Failure) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'm in a monad transformer with IO and I'd like to define my own instance for [Failure](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/failure-0.2.0.1/docs/Control-Failure.html).

Because Failure already defines instances for IO and for MonadTrans, I cannot even build my own overlapping instance.

As far as I know, I have four options left:

1. Newtyping IO:
   This is a little bit awkward, I would need to derive all that I want to change, and redefine the rest.
2. Hacking Failure to separate the class itself into it's own Module:
   I would move the class definition into a submodule Control.Failure.Class
3. Creating a Simple wrapper module for Failure without reexporting the instances
4. Removing MonadTrans from my Monad Transformer

Do you know any other option? What do you think?

Comment: It was actually a mistake in the failure library to define the MonadTrans instance for Failure. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Could you elaborate more on why it was a mistake?

Comment: Specifically for the reason mentioned in the question: there's no way to define a special instance for a transformer.

Comment: FYI: I've dumped ```Failure``` in favor for [lifted-base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base/docs/Control-Exception-Lifted.html), because getting ```Failure``` to throw anything else than IO-Exceptions wasn't worth the effort. anyway, I may be in a special situation here, because I already have ```MonadeBaseControl``` dependencies all over my code here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `newtype` wrapper is the standard approach to such a problem. The `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension makes optionally deriving instances from the wrapped monad a breeze.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

-- | Your custom monad transformer
newtype YourMonadT e m r = 
  YourMonadT (EitherT e m r)
  -- Easily derive the instances using the GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)

instance Failure e (YourMonadT e m) where
  failure = error "TODO: implement me however you want"
```